# Check if Swift String is one word

Tags: swift, string

How can I check if a string is just one word?

For example `"Dog"`, as opposed to `"Dog Dog"`.

Comment: Converting it into array and checking if Array.count == 0 makes any sense? Is it better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trim and split into an array with a white space character set. than just evaluate the count

```
let count = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).filter {$0 != ""}.count

switch count {
case 0:
    print("no word")
case 1:
    print("one word")

default:
    print("multiple words")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

```
let string = "Dog"

if string.components(separatedBy: " ").filter({ !$0.isEmpty}).count == 1 {
    print("One word")

} else {
    print("Not one word")

}
```

Let's apply that on " Dog" for example:

First, you need to get the components of the string separated by space, so you'll get:

> ["", "Dog"]

Then you need to exclude the empty strings by filtering the array.

After that, you only need to check the size of the array, if it's one, then there is only one word.

Comment: What about the case " Dog" ?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my code to fix that.

Comment: I updated the code again to make it simpler.